# How to add click listener when user tap on marker(google map) and should show bottom sheet?

Tags: android, google-maps, bottom-sheet

When user tap on marker a bottom sheet will appear.I'm not able to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add some code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bottom sheet fragment:

```
BottomDialogFragment bottomDialogFragment = BottomDialogFragment.getInstance();
```

then in your map add the following listener and launch the fragment on click:

```
yourMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    bottomDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), “Bottom Sheet Fragment");

                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Check [this](https://medium.com/@mujtahidah/bottom-sheet-dialog-fragment-android-6ac7dc36e6ac) if you don't know how to create the bottom dialog fragment